# Jackson json arraylist of unknown fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{
    "123": {
        "hi": {
            "name": "John",
            "phone": "12345"
        }
    },
    "124": {
        "hi": {
            "name": "James",
            "phone": "12345"
        }
    },
    "125": {
        "hi": {
            "name": "Leo",
            "phone": "12347"
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON is ordered externally: `123, 124, 125` I just want to get the value of the last field ("125" : **{...}**) but I don't know its name, is auto-generated. What's the best way?

I'm trying mapping to an `arrayList` of `JsonNodes`, but I don't find the right way.

Comment: I am afraid its name is "125", this is not an array

Comment: What are the exact properties the field names ("123", etc.) have? Your problem is that fields of an JSON object, which this is, are not ordered. So unless you have some ordering imposed on the field names by their names (for example lexicographically) it makes no sense to speak about the last field.

Comment: Hi Philipp. The Json is ordered externally in the same way that I wrote, 123, 124, 125, .... I just want to get the last field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it putting the JSON string in a JsonNode, data and mapping to a NavigableMap.

```
NavigableMap<String, JsonNode> updates = mapper.readValue(data.traverse(), new TypeReference<TreeMap<String, JsonNode>>() {});
Entry<String, JsonNode> lastEntry = updates.lastEntry();
String lastUpdate = lastEntry.getValue().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using `@JsonAnySetter` annotation. Please, see below example. POJO class:

```
class Node {

    private Integer key = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private JsonNode value;

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String newKey, JsonNode newValue) {
        if (Integer.valueOf(newKey) > key) {
            value = newValue;
        }
    }

    public JsonNode getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Node node = mapper.readValue(json), Node.class);
System.out.println(node);
```

Prints:

```
{"hi":{"name":"Leo","phone":"12347"}}
```